# Why should I care about the theory of biholomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

I reached the last chapter of our lecture about complex analysis. The chapter ist called "biholomorphic functions". Some keywords are: conformal mappings, Möbius transformations, biholomorphism and the Riemann mapping theorem(it is stated that this is one of the highlights of complex analysis). I try to understand all the things but it would be very helpful to have a good motivation because for now I don't really see a purpose in all of this. Maybe some of you could explain me why i should care about this topic and the riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: It means as far as domains are concerned, you need only look at functions on the unit disc or entire functions when studying holomorphic functions.

Comment: Did you ever wonder why in linear algebra we care about invertible matrices? Or in set theory care about bijections?

Comment: Riemann Mapping Theorem (and its generalization the Uniformization theorem ) are very specific to the complex plane setting and essentially  mean that there are only three universal complex spaces of dimension  1, unit disc (lots of bounded harmonic and holomorphic  functions), the plane (no bounded non constant holomorphic  functions but lots of unbounded ones), riemann sphere (only constant  holomorphic  functions)